# Python 3.9.0 - Physics simulation of drag working abnormally

Tags: python-3.x, simulation, projectile

```
def CalculateAcceleration(self):
    currentTheta = math.atan(self.velocity[1]/self.velocity[0])
    currentSquaredVelocity = math.pow(self.velocity[0],2)+math.pow(self.velocity[1],2)
    accelerationMagnitude = currentSquaredVelocity*self.coeffD
    self.acceleration = [math.cos(currentTheta)*accelerationMagnitude, math.sin(currentTheta)*accelerationMagnitude]
    self.acceleration = [self.acceleration[0], self.acceleration[1]-self.g]
```

I believe this is where the problem is and it only happens when the the projectile is going to the right.

[not working...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCJEs.png)

[working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7058w.png)

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the negative sign in the force calculation